# Caffe: Drawing CNN Net

Tags: python, caffe

I used python code to draw Net defined in prototext file as:

```
 python draw_net.py test.protxt test.png
```

It fails to draw. It does not show any error but the results test.png file is white blank image file. Can anyone please help me in fixing it? It would really help to design new nets quickly.

Comment: if you use NVIDIA's [DIGITS](https://github.com/NVIDIA/DIGITS) interface to caffe, you'll be able to get these drawing from the UI.

Comment: BTW how big is your net? can you draw smaller nets?

Comment: I can draw Siamese network( given in the library) but can not draw nets for Imagenet classification ( given in the library too)

Comment: `f@f-VirtualBox:~/caffe/caffe-master/python$ python draw_net.py ../models/bvlc_reference_caffenet/train_val.prototxt train_val.prototxt.png` works fine on my side: image is not blank.

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem. Based on [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/caffe-users/d6fpZTOq5M0), I've managed to solve this by using older Proto syntax as suggested. For instance I had to do this:

Rename layers definition from `layers` to `layer`. All layer type rename by caffe documentation (or by example proto files) - i.e. layer `type: CONVOLUTION` to `type: "Convolution"`, etc. Substitute newer syntax:

```
blobs_lr: 1         
blobs_lr: 1         
weight_decay: 1
weight_decay: 0
```

for

```
param {
    name: "conv1_w"
    lr_mult: 1              
    decay_mult: 1
}
param {
    name: "conv1_b"
    lr_mult: 2              
    decay_mult: 0
}
```

Now parsing and new-drawing works just fine. Refer to example .prototxt files in caffe package to get better intuition, how working proto syntax looks like.

Answer (score 2):

Somwhere in mid 2014, Caffe [changed their proto definition for extensibility](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/releases/tag/v0.999) which causes this problem. As a result of this change, all the proto files have to be updated to the newer definition.

To do this, Caffe provides the following tools in the `distribute/bin/` or `.build_release/tools` directory:

1. `upgrade_net_proto_binary.bin`
2. `upgrade_net_proto_text.bin`

Here is a simple example of how to convert your proto text file to a newer format:

```
./upgrade_net_proto_text.bin /path/to/older_proto_file /path/to/newer_ouput_proto_file
```